# how to return a field in with as

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my image table, I need to insert data from the csv_images table.

I have to insert the link from the image.

In the poi_image table, I have to insert the id of the image table (so the d.id), but I also have to insert an id from another table (poi id table).

The csv_images table contains a field (uri_id) which corresponds to the uri_id field of the poi table).

I must therefore insert in my poi_images table the id of poi which corresponds to pooi.uri_id and csv_adresse.uri_id.

So I use the With as, but I cannot transmit csv_adresses.uri_id to the next step to be able to reuse it:

```
WITH image_insert AS (
   INSERT INTO image
         (lien_image)
   SELECT c.lien
   FROM   csv_images c
    join poi p on p.uri_id = c.poi
    group by lien
    
   RETURNING  *,  p.uri_id
   )

INSERT INTO poi_images (poi_id, image_id)
SELECT p.uri_id,  d.id 
FROM   image_insert d;
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tricky because Postgres only allows you to return the values in the row being inserted.  In your case, `lien_image` is unique (because of the `GROUP BY`) so one option is to reconstruct the values using`JOIN`:

```
WITH image_insert AS (
     INSERT INTO image (lien_image)
         SELECT c.lien
         FROM csv_images c JOIN
              poi p 
              ON p.uri_id = c.poi
         GROUP BY c.lien
         RETURNING *
   )
INSERT INTO poi_images (poi_id, image_id)
    SELECT c.poi,  ii.id 
    FROM image_insert ii JOIN
         csv_images c
         ON c.lien = ii.lien_image ;
```

Comment: thank you but precisely, I use the group by link because I have duplicates in the csv_images table. Using your solution ON c.lien = ii.lien_image; , unless I am mistaken, I risk finding links (csv_image table) which have not been inserted in the images table. The join equality may link a csv_images table row that was not used during the previous insert

Comment: it is also likely that a single image link is for 1 or more 'poi'

Comment: Or I modify my design of the image table to add the uri_id of csv_image to ensure integrity ...

Comment: I think the best is to make a loop on the table csv_image no ?

Comment: @Camel4488 . . . If you include `poi` in `image_insert`, then that will definitely simplify this query.